# Discord js economy commands to command handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have recently been working on both my first economy system and my first command handler. I have managed to get my '-balance' command properly integrated with the command handler but I am struggling to integrate the other commands as async does not work with the command handler. If anyone can help me fully integrate the commands into the command handler that would be greatly appreciated

economy code: (index.js)

```js
Reflect.defineProperty(currency, 'add', {
    value: async function add(id, amount) {
        const user = currency.get(id);
        if (user) {
            user.balance += Number(amount);
            return user.save();
        }
        const newUser = await Users.create({ user_id: id, balance: amount });
        currency.set(id, newUser);
        return newUser;
    },
});

Reflect.defineProperty(currency, 'getBalance', {
    value: function getBalance(id) {
        const user = currency.get(id);
        return user ? user.balance : 0;
    },
});

client.once('ready', async () => {
    const storedBalances = await Users.findAll();
    storedBalances.forEach(b => currency.set(b.user_id, b));
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    currency.add(message.author.id, 1);

    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;
    const input = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim();
    if (!input.length) return;
    const [, command, commandArgs] = input.match(/(\w+)\s*([\s\S]*)/);
    /*
    if (command === 'balance') {
        const target = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
        return message.channel.send(`${target.tag} has ${currency.getBalance(target.id)}`);
        */

    if (command === 'buy') { //} else
        const item = await CurrencyShop.findOne({ where: { name: { [Op.like]: commandArgs } } });
        if (!item) return message.channel.send('That item doesn\'t exist.');
        if (item.cost > currency.getBalance(message.author.id)) {
            return message.channel.send(`You don't have enough currency, ${message.author}`);
        }
        const user = await Users.findOne({ where: { user_id: message.author.id } });
        currency.add(message.author.id, -item.cost);
        await user.addItem(item);

        message.channel.send(`You've bought a ${item.name}`);
    }

    if (command === 'shop') { 
        const items = await CurrencyShop.findAll();
        return message.channel.send(items.map(i => `${i.name}: ${i.cost}`).join('\n'), { code: true });
    } else if (command === 'leaderboard') {
        return message.channel.send(
            currency.sort((a, b) => b.balance - a.balance)
                .filter(user => client.users.cache.has(user.user_id))
                .first(10)
                .map((user, position) => `(${position + 1}) ${(client.users.cache.get(user.user_id).tag)}: ${user.balance}`)
                .join('\n'),
            { code: true }
        );
    }
});
```

Command Handler:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const command = client.commands.get(commandName)
        || client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));

    if (!command) return;

    if (command.guildOnly && message.channel.type !== 'text') {
        return message.reply('I can\'t execute that command inside DMs!');
    }

    if (command.args && !args.length) {
        let reply = `You didn't provide any arguments, ${message.author}!`;

        if (command.usage) {
            reply += `\nThe proper usage would be: \`${prefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}\``;
        }

        return message.channel.send(reply);
    }

    if (!cooldowns.has(command.name)) {
        cooldowns.set(command.name, new Discord.Collection());
    }

    const now = Date.now();
    const timestamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
    const cooldownAmount = (command.cooldown || 3) * 1000;

    if (timestamps.has(message.author.id)) {
        const expirationTime = timestamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldownAmount;

        if (now < expirationTime) {
            const timeLeft = (expirationTime - now) / 1000;
            return message.reply(`please wait ${timeLeft.toFixed(1)} more second(s) before reusing the \`${command.name}\` command.`);
        }
    }

    timestamps.set(message.author.id, now);
    setTimeout(() => timestamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldownAmount);

    try {
        command.execute(message, args);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe `async` does work with a command handler, like this

```js
async execute(message) {
// code
    },
```

Also just import the currency const into each command file which needs it.